# How to change welcome intent of your Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I got the following error after I submitted my project for production from the review team:
In the welcome intent of your Action, it refers to itself as “The Fun Trivia Game” instead of  your app name.
How to solve this?

Comment: Check welcome intent in your dialogflow console

Comment: You may be using event such as `actions_intent_PLAY_GAME`. Also, check your invocation name and invocation phrases, it may not be same.